# Integrate simple bootstrap template into Angular

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, frontend

I created a new angular application with `ng new test-app`. Now I want to use this very basic template [Start Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/starter-template/).

How can I do this?

What I did so far:

1. I executed `npm install bootstrap`
2. I added `node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css` to the `angular.json` file

As far as I can see, I have everything available now. Now I just copy the `<body>...</body>` from the `html`-Template to `app.component.html` but I delete the bottom stuff with the jQuery scripts.

Well, the result is that it looks similar but far away from nice. What am I doing wrong? Is something missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the solution was simple:

1. I forgot to add the bootstrap script to the `angular.json`. So I added `node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js` to the scripts.
2. I used a bootstrap4 template while I installed bootstrap5. So I switched to a bootstrap5 template.

Everything works fine!

Note: Obviously you have to check if the template has some extra css settings or some extra packages.

Comment: Alright, you have solved it yourself :) But if change it again in the angular.json file, just don't forget to restart the application.